# Pdf Bookmarks not working in Bartekc Android Pdf Library

Tags: android, pdf, bookmarks, pdf-viewer, pdfium

### Bookmarks not working in Barteksc Pdf Library

I am currently using the **Barteksc Pdf library** (v.3.1.0-Beta) for my Android app. But, the Barteksc Pdf library is not Supporting Pdf ***Bookmarks***. When I click on the bookmark on my android app it doesn't respond to anything. But Pdfium that is used by chrome perfectly works with ***Bookmarks***. If Anyone knows any Pdfium library which supports Pdf Bookmarks. Please share with me!

Thanks in Advance!

### Edit:

This is How Chrome opens a Interactive Pdf

**(When, Clicking my Pdf's Bookmark. It works!)**

[image: This is how Chrome supports Pdf Bookmarks!]

Comment: Does anybody know the Answer to this? Plz help needed!

Comment: Otherwise, Plz start bounty for this question! Plz